# How do I show App Insights (Monthly Users/etc) on the Facebook Page for that App?

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-page

FB has announced that all 'app-specific-pages' will be need to be migrated to the standard FB pages (by Feb/2012). Previously App-pages were automatically showing useful insight information like Monthly Users for the underlying app. Now that there is a standard Page, which has no knowledge of the app, how do we display App-related insights on the new page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply look at the insights for the application itself.

https://www.facebook.com/insights/
This of course is assuming that you have the permission to see the insights of that specific application.